# External Hive Table with 0 records

Tags: apache-spark, hive, external-tables

I want to create an external hive table in spark AWS with just the schema and 0 records. Expectation is when i select the external hive table, i should see just the schema with no records.

Comment: what are you trying which is giving error/problem achieving this ?

Comment: can you use `CREATE TABLE xtmp LIKE tmp` ? This will create empty table.